# Why is `Type` of calling function not `reference` in `JavaScript(ECMA-262 5.1)`?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-5

My question arose while I was trying to figure out all the details of `this` keyword. So far, I understood that how this value is set by reading ECMAScript® Language Specification Section [10.4.3 Entering Function Code](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-10.4.3) and [11.2.3 Function Call](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-11.2.3). And while doing playing with some code, my question arose, please see the code below.

```
"use strict";
function test(){
alert(this); //undefined
};
test();
```

According to [10.4.3](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-10.4.3) Step 1, given `thisArg` is assigned to `this` value in `strict mode`. And according to [11.2.3](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-11.2.3) Step 7, thisArg is only undefined when `Type(ref)` is not a `reference`.

So my question is, why is `Type(ref)` not a `reference` in this case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Step 7 is irrelevant in this case because it is the *else* after step 6, which says:

> 6.If Type(ref) is Reference, then 
>   a.If IsPropertyReference(ref) is true, then 
>   i.Let thisValue be GetBase(ref). 
>   b.Else, the base of ref is an Environment Record 
>   i.Let thisValue be the result of calling the ImplicitThisValue concrete method of GetBase(ref).

In your case `test`*is* a Reference, and it is *not* a PropertyReference, so the ImplicitThisValue is used. In strict mode, that value is `undefined`.

Comment: You are right, i was wrong. So for all calling function declaration, it returns undefined?

Comment: @beli Basically, there are four possible outcomes: 1. the function is bound and `this` is always that bound value: `var func = function () { console.log(this) }.bind("Hello!"); func();` 2. you call an unbound function as a property reference and `this` is the "base" of that property reference: `var o = { f: function () { console.log(this); } }; o.f();` 3. you call an unbound function by itself and `this` is undefined: `function f() { console.log(this); } f();`. 4. you call an unbound function with `.call()` or `.apply()` and `this` is whatever you specify.

Comment: @beli That Javascript spec sure is convoluted isn't it? I guess those are the kind of contortions you need to go through to thoroughly define a language that was designed in 10 days. :)

Comment: Yes, the spec is pretty tricky. I hope there is some book that interpreted it with rich examples.

Comment: @beli There are thousands of books on Javascript. You don't need to read the spec to understand Javascript. :)

Comment: I am reading `JavaScript for professional web developers, 3rd Edition`, and it does not have much explanation about `this` keyword so far. The only thing it says about `this` keyword is that it returns the context object that current context is operating on. So I researched it on my own. :D